# How to detect light-up unlock and unlock of the screen in background

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am working on an android app trying to record the usage of the phone. For one function, I am trying to detect whether the screen is light up (not necessary to be unlocked), unlock and lock. How can I capture this three kinds of behavior of user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a `BroadcastReceiver`
Use Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ACTION_SCREEN_ON to detect screen on/off event
Guideline about how to use BroadcastReceiver can be found here
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html